# Plotting raster data and points

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a dataframe of points and plotted it using `plot`. Now I want to add a RasterLayer of AnnualTemp. Can you please assist in completing the code?

```
library(raster)

MinTemp_plots <- data.frame(
  Station = c( "Labasa", "Laucala", "Lautoka", "Levuka", "Matei", "Matuku",
               "Nabouwalu", "Nacocolevu",  "Nadi", "Nausori",  "Ono-I-Lau",  "Penang",
               "Savusavu",   "UduPoint",   "Viwa", "Yasawa"),
  
  Latitude = c(-16.43, -18.15, -17.6, -17.68, -16.69, -19.15, -16.98,
               -18.1,  -17.75, -18.03, -20.65, -17.37, -16.78, -16.11,
               -17.14, -16.78 ),
  
  Longitude = c(179.36, 178.45, 177.45, 178.83, 180, 179.76, 178.7, 177.55,
                177.45, 178.56, 178.7, 178.15, 179.34, 180, 176.93,
                177.5),
  
  AnnualTempMin = c(1.722, 1.711, 0.042, 0.135, 0.264, 0.276, 0.625, 1.215,  
                    1.522, 0.917,  0.617, 0.072, 0.509, 1.057, 1.201, 0.123))


plot(y= MinTemp_plots$Latitude, x= MinTemp_plots$Longitude)

r <- raster(xmn=1790828.61, xmx=2337149.40, ymn=3577110.39, ymx=4504717.19, res=100000)
crs(r) = crs("+init=epsg:3460")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what your question is, but here goes:

Add values to the example RasterLayer for plotting

```
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
```

Create a SpatialPointsDataFrame

```
x <- MinTemp_plots
coordinates(x) <- ~ Longitude + Latitude
crs(x) <- "+proj=longlat"
```

Transform it to the same coordinate reference system as the raster

```
y <- spTransform(x, crs(r))
```

And now plot

```
plot(r)
points(y)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering my question. The aim of my plot is to get a raster layer for AnnualTemperature data  [ AnnualTempMin = c(1.722, 1.711, 0.042, 0.135, 0.264, 0.276, 0.625, 1.215,  1.522, 0.917,  0.617, 0.072, 0.509, 1.057, 1.201, 0.123)] .... the latitude and longitude is given and to set the crs to epsg:3460. Hope to improve.